# autogen.sh - no such file or directory

Tags: libimobiledevice

I'm at the [Get Started](https://libimobiledevice.org/#get-started) build instructions for libimobiledevice:

#### Build

Enter the commands provided below.

```
$ ./autogen.sh \
    --prefix=/opt/local \
    --enable-debug
$ make
```

... and I see the following error:

```
bash: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory
```

So, where can I get this file?

Answer (score 0):

I missed the part where you need to download those libraries, but then I found [these docs](https://gist.github.com/alain-andre/afe4333465f44e9248ce1a7d6b5f4082). However, it still wasn't working for me because `fuse` was not installed on my system. Fortunately, I found [another article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/easily-mount-your-iphone-as-an-external-drive-in-ubuntu/) which explained that process. Now I can successfully pair my phone and mount it, but I only see iOS related folders. Is that normal?